# Why does winrar duplicate an entire archive when adding to it

Tags: archiving, winrar

I just noticed that instead of adding files to the archive winrar actually just duplicates the current archive and then adds the files on top of everything else... personally it makes absolutely no sense to rewrite an entire file just to add something to it

makes even less sense when dealing with a 87,668,719,616 byte archive

is there a way around this. i only have 28,388,671,488 bytes free so you can see my dilemma... i created an archive in order to save some space and now i find out that i need my twice the volume of my archive to update it...

the other failing to these archiving programs is the "Delete files after archiving" Option... its fairly useless when dealing with more then a Singular File... it would be a lot more useful if they had "Delete each file after processing"

but as it stands not even 7zip has that option -.-'

Comment: its just a bunch of old .ISO games that take up 40-50% more bytes uncompressed 

all i want to do is add 3 more files to the archive but instead of just adding the files it makes an exact duplicate of the archive im trying to add these 3 files to and then adds the files.... that's like copying an entire book just so you can add more pages to it.... the logic makes about as much sense as Monkey-Pig-Bird that Craps Ice-cream

Comment: so instead of it just processing 3 files it re-processes the entire archive plus 3 files...

even if it was adding a new entry to the table of contents why the hell does it need to re-pack every file in the archive the table of contents should only be a few bytes large

Comment: I guess you should compress each file individually instead of putting them all into one huge archive. You could even use Windows' compact command so you don't have to extract them to be able to use/read the files. e.g. `compact /c /exe:lzx image.iso`

Comment: well i guess compressing them individually is really all im left with, im not really concerned with being able to use/read the files im just concerned with compression im running out of free space

but i guess i now have a whole new problem... how am i going to extract the files from the archive without the required space to create a larger double of the archive...

joy... is... me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does this because by default WinRar works as what is known as a 'solid archive', in that the files to be compressed are sorted and compressed as a single stream in order to find duplicate data *across files* instead of simply *within individual files*.

In order to compress any new files in a solid archive it first needs to process the entire archive in order to build the compression dictionary that is used to compress the files and insert the new file into the data stream. This means effectively decompressing and recompressing the archive.

If you don't want this behaviour then you need to disable the "solid archive" option which will compress files individually and allow files to simply be compressed and appended to the end of the archive. This has the drawback of not searching for compressible data that is duplicated between input files and so will increase archive size, especially if you have files which are exact duplicates.

You basically have a choice: speed of compression when adding new files or getting the best compression ratio possible.

Comment: Solid archive is not the default as far as i know. But even if the archive is not solid WinRar will still copy it if you append a file so you still need enough disk space. It won't recompress it though.

Comment: well i guess the re-processing kinda makes sense in those terms, still it kind of makes all archive programs obsolete then since editing/updating a large Compressed file will end up taking more time then just manually decompressing adding the files in and re-compressing it.

i figured the Adding option worked like a Patch Loader that's used to update games, ya know when your updating your WoW Client it doesn't download & reinstall your entire client it just adds and updates the specified files

i just go figured it worked by the same principle